# I am getting this error "The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.ClientOptions' threw an exception"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

public static string SendMail(MailInfo mail)
{
string str = "";

```
    try
    {
        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenant, _clientId, _clientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

        var message = new Message
        {
            Subject = mail.Subject,
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = mail.Message
            },
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
        {
            new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = mail.ToAddress }}
        }
        };
        graphServiceClient.Users[mail.FromAddress].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().Wait();

        str = "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        str = "Exception";
    }

    return str;
```

}

This is my code .

I am getting in error on this line

var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenant, _clientId, _clientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });

In server inside my log i am getting the error this kinds of line

ERROR 2022-12-26 12:25:24,250 2186 Registration2 Forgototp - ameen@abi-tech.com.sg
ERROR 2022-12-26 12:25:24,297 2233 MailHelper SendForgetPassword - SendForgetPassword:ameen@abi-tech.com.sg 7472
Ameen
ERROR 2022-12-26 12:25:24,313 2249 MailHelper SendForgetPassword - The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.ClientOptions' threw an exception.

at Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions..ctor()
at ABIWHIZ.MailHelper.SendMail(MailInfo mail) in C:\Users\ABI-Tech Tele-Call\Downloads\DigitalID Latest\ABIWHIZ\Helpers\MailHelper.cs:line 360
at ABIWHIZ.MailHelper.SendForgetPassword(String Email, String Password, String name) in C:\Users\ABI-Tech Tele-Call\Downloads\DigitalID Latest\ABIWHIZ\Helpers\MailHelper.cs:line 287

Please help me to complete my task